# Match names in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I would like to match names based on frequency of usage. For instance, I want to match Elizabeth and Liz as same as most frequently Elizabeth is nick named as Liz. Same for William and Will. I am using Elastic Search for fuzzy logic. So far i am able to match Will and Bill based on edit distance. But I want to further improve my search.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think you'll need to define synonyms for really good results. Fuzzy matches will definitely be too limited. Maybe ngrams will get you quite far, but they might also lead to weird results; eg trigrams for 3 letters would find Liz in E**liz**abeth, but also **Eth**an,...

Comment: Thanks for the response.